# Sorting a User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

```
@users = User.all
```

---

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>

     <%= user.name %>

 <% end %>
```

How would I sort this by name and not the id

Comment: It would be worth showing how you are querying to set the value `@users` as this would be the best point to do the ordering if possible.

Comment: Note that by default there is no order, as SQL doesn't guarantee one if you don't specify explicitly. Any perceived order is coincidental.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@users = User.order('name ASC')
```

in your controller

As suggested, you can also set `default_scope` instead of calling `User.order('name asc')` everywhere:

```
default_scope order('name ASC')
```

or you can set scope:

```
scope :name_ordered, order('name ASC')
```

and call it with

```
User.name_ordered
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Marek Lipka answer: may be you want to get users with the order everytime, then add to the model

```
default_scope order('name asc')
```

Instead of putting it everywhere like

```
User.order('name asc').all
```

Comment: Note though that you have to unscope the relation whenever you want a different order.